# OroCRM Adding attachment fields to an entity through migration

Tags: php, symfony, orocrm

I added two attachment fields to the Lead entity, when I go to the Entity Managment on the frontend I can see that the fields were added, but when I create a Lead the fields are not showing. Also when I try to view a Lead I get this exception:

> *An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template (“An exception occurred while executing ‘SELECT count(o0_.id) AS sclr0 FROM
>   oro_attachment o0_ LEFT JOIN orocrm_sales_lead o1_ ON
>   o0_.lead_5b29b7d2_id = o1_.id AND (o1_.organization_id = 1) WHERE
>   o1_.id = ? AND o0_.organization_id = 1′ with params ["101"]:
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   ‘o0_.lead_5b29b7d2_id’ in ‘on clause’”) in
>   /var/www/html/crm-application/vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/AttachmentBundle/Resources/views/Attachment/widget/attachments.html.twig
>   at line 1.*

So my question is: do I have to do something to activate such fields?
Note: I added two more string-typed fields to the Lead entity and they show in the grid and the creation form.
I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

try to clear cache or remove it completely,
did you pressed "Update schema" red button?

Comment: Yes I pressed the Update Schema button but an error massage came up with no information at all.

Comment: check app/log/dev.log or prod.log depending on environment, there should be full description of some exception